# Es necesario Instalar el ODAC en Producción para conexión a la base de datos?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

tengo una maquina de desarrollo con VS2015 Oracle 10g, me conecto con EF6, en mi maquina de desarrollo tengo instalado el ODAC 12 release 4, ORacle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, bueno y todo funciona bien, la pregunta es, en  mi entorno de producción que tengo que tener instalado para que funcione las conexiones? o solo basta con las DLL generadas? Alguien me podría guiar al respecto o proporcionarme los Links de Oracle donde se especifique bien este tema? Gracias

Answer (score 1):

**>>en mi entorno de producción que tengo que tener instalado para que funcione las conexiones?**

Si es necesario tener instalado ODAC en todo cliente que quiera conectarse a la base de datos, mas que nada porque requiere poder interpretar el tnsname.ora, etc

Aunque analizando el tema podrias ver si instalado solamente el `Oracle Instant Client` alcanza y parece ser mas liviano

[How can I deploy a .NET application that uses ODAC without installing the whole component to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935808/how-can-i-deploy-a-net-application-that-uses-odac-without-installing-the-whole)

Lo que si recomendaria es hacer la prueba previa y no realizar esto en la pc de produccion, no se si usas maquinas virtuales (puedes usar [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)), entonces podrias armar una que simule tu entorno de produccion, configurando la aplicacion y validar instalando el Oracle Instant Client, o quizas requieres el ODAC completo

Tambien puedo ver que mencionan una forma de lograrlo sin ODAC,

[Accessing Oracle database without installing Oracle Client](https://begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/accessing-oracle-database-without-installing-oracle-client/)

pero la verdad no estoy seguro que de resultado